# I found what looks like a crystal oscillator with an xdl stamp I haven't seen before

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I found an old transmitter with a crystal oscillator on it, when I looked at this I saw that it had "xdl 17.734475m" stamped onto it, I've only ever seen oscillators with just their frequency written on them.

I tried searching the internet but it just came up with Chinese websites, so I was wondering what the "xdl" meant (brand name?) and what the "m" after the number means.

Any thoughts?

P.s. I'm fairly new to this so I'm not sure my terms are completely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XDL could be either manufacturer, or (more likely) the series.

The "17.734475m" is the frequency, meaning 17.734475 MHz.

It seems like a silly frequency, but it's the PAL B/G/H color subcarrier (4×4.433618 MHz) (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator_frequencies)).